# Insert list into my database using Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I want to insert a list in my database but I can't.

Here is an example of what I need:

```
variable_1 = "HELLO"
variable_2 = "ADIOS"
list = [variable_1,variable_2]

INSERT INTO table VALUES ('%s') % list
```

Can something like this be done? Can I insert a list as a value?
When I try it, an error says that is because of an error in MySQL syntax

Comment: In general, if you have an error message, you should include it in the question.

Comment: why not use redis?if use ast and redis-py module,u can write a list to redis.eg.r.set(a,[1,23,3]).when u need this object ,u can use b = ast.literal_eval(r.get(a)) to get the list

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer to your original question is:  No, you can't insert a list like that.

However, with some tweaking, you could make that code work by using `%r` and passing in a tuple:

```
variable_1 = "HELLO"
variable_2 = "ADIOS"
varlist = [variable_1, variable_2]
print "INSERT INTO table VALUES %r;" % (tuple(varlist),)
```

Unfortunately, that style of variable insertion leaves your code vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Instead, we recommend using [Python's DB API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) and building a customized query string with multiple question marks for the data to be inserted:

```
variable_1 = "HELLO"
variable_2 = "ADIOS"
varlist = [variable_1,variable_2]
var_string = ', '.join('?' * len(varlist))
query_string = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s);' % var_string
cursor.execute(query_string, varlist)
```

The example at the beginning of the [SQLite3 docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3) shows how to pass arguments using the question marks and it explains why they are necessary (essentially, it assures correct quoting of your variables).

Comment: where do we specify the column name where I want to insert the values? Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72641938/add-list-values-to-a-mysql-column

Answer (score 6):

Your question is not clear.

Do you want to insert the list as a comma-delimited text string into a single column in the database?  Or do you want to insert each element into a separate column?  Either is possible, but the technique is different.

Insert comma-delimited list into one column:

> ```
>  conn.execute('INSERT INTO table (ColName) VALUES (?);', [','.join(list)])
> ```

Insert into separate columns:

> ```
>   params = ['?' for item in list]
>   sql    = 'INSERT INTO table (Col1, Col2. . .) VALUES (%s);' % ','.join(params)
>   conn.execute(sql, list)
> ```

both assuming you have established a connection name conn.

A few other suggestions:

- Try to avoid INSERT statements that do not list the names and order of the columns you're inserting into.  That kind of statement leads to very fragile code; it breaks if you add, delete, or move columns around in your table.
- If you're inserting a comma-separted list into a single-field, that generally violates principals of database design and you should use a separate *table* with one value per record.
- If you're inserting into separate fields and they have names like `Word1` and `Word2`, that is likewise an indication that you should be using a separate table instead.
- Never use direct string substitution to create SQL statements.  It will break if one of the values is, for example `o'clock`.  It also opens you to attacks by people using SQL injection techniques.

Comment: HI Larry....
I want to insert two diferent strings in the same column....so when I make the Query to obtain what is inside that colum....I know that there are two different strings.....that's why I am trying to insert the value as a list

Comment: You cannot do that.  A column can hold only one string.  You can have a comma in that string to make it look like two different strings, but obviously that doesn't work if one of the strings *already* has a comma.  But you should look up the idea of database normalization and redesign your database to use a separate, related table to hold these values.  Never, ever, ever put more than one value into a database column.

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72641938/add-list-values-to-a-mysql-column

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json.dumps` to convert a list to json and write the json to db.

For example:

```
insert table example_table(column_name) values(json.dumps(your_list))
```

Comment: This example is very confusing. You can't use a Python function like `json.dumps` from inside your SQL string. You would have to call `json.dumps` first, then use one of the parameter substitution methods suggested in other answers to pass the resulting JSON string as a parameter. It's also not usually a good idea to store JSON strings in a database column.