# How to insert a list containing values seperated by comma into MySQL database using python

Tags: python, mysql, list, sql-insert, mysql-python

I have to insert a list having integer values into a column of MySQL database table using Python. First I tried

```
cur.execute("insert into time_Interval (name, time_interval_list) values (%s, %s)",\
        #   (user_name, interval_list))
```

Where "interval_list" is the list variable having values that I want to insert into "time_interval_list" column of "time_Interval" table. Code is working but does not insert the values. Then I tried  [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316176/insert-list-into-my-database-using-python) changing the code as

```
var_string = ','.join('?' * len(interval_list))
cur.execute("insert into time_Interval (name, time_interval_list) values (%s, %s)",\
            (user_name, var_string))
```

Again, code was working fine but inserts a list of question mark. I am unable to find the solution.

How to do this correctly. Any suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
var_string = ','.join('?' * len(interval_list))
```

to

```
var_string = ','.join(interval_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, actually I have to typecast it as a string list

Answer (score 0):

The following code helped me bulk insert data into a database table using Python.

You can first create a tuple of tuples from the data you want to insert as follows

`var_string = ','.join(cur.mogrify("(%s,%s)", x).decode('utf-8') for x in interval_list)`

The `interval_list` would include both name and time_interval_list values whehn creating the tuple of tuples. Then run exceute command giving the tuple of tuples as input to the values.

`cur.execute("INSERT INTO time_Interval (name, time_interval_list) VALUES " + var_string)`

This command bulk inserts data into a database table very quickly.