# Insert list of values into postgres database

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a very long list of values:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 .......]
```

and the following query to insert them in to postgres database:

```
connection.execute(
        'INSERT INTO data_core_cftcreport VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s)',
        mylist)
```

This works as expected however it doesn't look good....

My question： **Is there any way I can shorten the VALUES declaration?**

I tried to do this, kind of borrowing from MySql, but it didn't work:

```
connection.execute('INSERT INTO data_core_cftcreport VALUES %s', mylist)
```

Comment: this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316176/insert-list-into-my-database-using-python