# Read from list into MySql

Tags: python, mysql

Here is my code to read from some data into MySql, the Mysql table contains 3 columns that in one of the columns I want to insert items of an array, each into a new row, and I do not want to have duplicate rows:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "M0", "my", local_infile=True,use_unicode=True, charset="utf8")
cursor = db.cursor()
r=["2","3"]
params = ['?' for item in r]
sql="insert ignore into array (firt,last_name,arrays) values 'nina','sa',(%s);" % ','.join(params)
cursor.execute(sql,r)
db.commit();
db.close()
```

I have already looked into this post [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316176/insert-list-into-my-database-using-python) as well !

However, on both of them I get this error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

any suggestions, please?

Comment: Have you tried printing your params?

Comment: Please print your query (with the actual parameter values) and show it.

Comment: @mad_  , just did! it shows "?" !!! why is this happening?

Comment: you are iterating n number of times and assigning '?' each time. You really don't need your params list. Correct that and edit the post

Comment: @mad_  I corrected that, I was not assigning parameters to the list! but getting the error that has been posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you just iterate over the set

```
r=set(["2","3"])
for item in r:
    sql="insert ignore into array (firt,last_name,arrays) values 'nina','sa',({})".format(item)
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: A follow up question has been posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824426/having-multiple-lists-and-inserting-their-values-into-mysql